# Can I use custom UI Elements or must they be Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to implement a custom text field with javascript and css. Is this allowed in the ionic fromework? Or will it not work?

Answer (score 0):

It's just plain web with HTML, CSS and Javascript. What Ionic provides are the basic bootstrap for an application and their own UI elements with styling. So, it's your choice to define your own set of elements or customize Ionic's.